# How unpredictable is the auto generated id of couchdb?

Tags: security, couchdb

Can I rely on the assumption that each generated id is random, and there's no way to user can guess? So that I don't need to do more double check of ownership and what not, on my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you will only get random uuids if you configure your instance to use the [`random` algorithm](https://couchdb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config/misc.html?highlight=_id%20random%20utc#uuids). When looking at [the source](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/blob/635022b27cf72efe82bc30f56393070f2b842615/src/couchdb/couch_uuids.erl#L32) you can see that it then uses Erlang's [crypto:rand_bytes/1](http://erlang.org/doc/man/crypto.html#rand_bytes-1). I'm not sure how predictable its results are, but you should note that there would also be [crypto:strong_rand_bytes/1](http://erlang.org/doc/man/crypto.html#strong_rand_bytes-1) - not sure why it hasn't been used.

I think the decision mostly depends on other circumstances.

- What information are you trying to secure?
- Why do you want to avoid ownership-checks as an additional security measure?
- How do you ensure that the _ids are not leaked somehow (eg through CouchDB's [`/_log` API](https://couchdb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/server/common.html#log))?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't rely on that, no.  A malicious user could make a *lot* of random guesses and could eventually hit something.  Best to let identifiers identify things and security restrictions secure them.